# Show that $A \setminus (B \setminus C)$ is equivalent to $(A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap C)$?

Tags: logic

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my work:

Expressing the first part $A \setminus (B\setminus C)$ using logical symbols:

$A \land \neg(B \land \neg C)$ becomes

$A \land \neg B\lor C$ (De Morgan's law)

While the second expression $(A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap C)$ is

$(A \land \neg B) \lor (A \land C)$ which becomes

$A \land \neg B \lor A \land C$ (Associative Law)

or $A \land \neg B \land C$

How are these two expressions similar? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: $$A \land \lnot (B \land \lnot C) = A \land (\lnot B \lor C) = (A \land \lnot B) \lor (A \land C)$$

Comment: Got it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put parentheses out - otherwise it's easy to get the order of the operations wrong (and I think you have when applying the demorgan law first time):

$$A\land(\neg B\lor C)$$

Then you use the associative law to get

$$(A\land \neg B)\lor(A\land C)$$

Which is what you're after.

---

The second part of your proof is wrong since you possibly due to missing parentheses or you confuse $\land$ and $\lor$ in the last step. Applying the associative law (reversly) on $(A\land\neg B)\lor(A\land C)$ would result in $A\land(\neg B\lor C)$. Using it (twice) forwardly would get:

$$(A\lor(A\land C)) \land (\neg B \lor (A\land C))$$
$$(A\lor A)\land(A\lor C) \land (\neg B\lor A)\land (\neg B\lor C)$$

Then you would need to use idempotence on $A\lor A$ and absorption by $A$ on the $A\lor C$ and $A\lor \neg B$ terms and get:

$$A\land (\neg B\lor C)$$

Which is where we started.

Answer (score 0):

From $(A \land \neg B) \lor (A \land C)$ you want to use the distributive law, not the associative law that's not applicable here:
$$
(\color{red}{A} \color{green}{\land} \neg B) \color{blue}{\lor} (\color{red}{A} \color{green}{\land} C)
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\color{red}{A}\color{green}{\land}(\neg B\color{blue}{\lor}C)
$$